# Meaning of "outweigh (our dreams)"

Tags: meaning-in-context

> When our memories outweigh our dreams, it is then that we become old.

What's the meaning of "outweigh" here?

Does it mean that our brains cannot dream anymore, or that we cannot make dreams into real anymore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we are young, we are full of vigor and ideals and we think about our

> dreams and ambitions

there are also fewer things to look back on (our memories), but as we get older, or memories start to accumulate and begin to weigh more (metaphorically). We have also experienced life, which is not easy, and our memories may be happier than out future prospects. We may begin to

> [yearn for the good old days](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/culture/11349364/Why-we-yearn-for-the-good-old-days.html)

What the sentence is saying is that our motivation to "make things happen" diminish as we get older

> [Eight years ago I was a young man, full of idealism and vigor, and look at me now. I'm grey, grizzled. Just counting down the days to my death panel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hA5ezR0Kh80&t=3m50s)

this may be because we no longer *want* to dream anymore, not necessarily because we *can't*.  This can be referred to as "cynicism". A person can always dream at any age, but what they *do* with those dreams is a different story.

Answer (score 2):

The phrase uses the metaphor of a scale, the "weight" of memories versus the "weight" of dreams.  A "dream" is a hope for the future (as well as a mental state when one is asleep). When our memories outnumber our dreams, they weigh more than our dreams.

Something which is heavier than another thing is said to "outweigh" it.  Here, the weights are equal:

```
MEMORIES                      DREAMS
------------------------------------
                ^
```

And here, memories "outweigh" dreams:

```
                              DREAMS                                  

MEMORIES
MEMORIES
                 ^
```

Answer (score 1):

In the literal sense, "outweigh" means "to be heavier than". In the metaphorical sense, "outweigh" means that it's more significant and carries more "weight" - so your sentence would mean:

> When we care more about our memories than about our dreams, it is then that we become old.